# Bootstrap 3 CSS Table Half Width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to have a table that only uses half the screen.

```
<table class="table">
....
</table>
```

By default this fills the whole width which is usually fine, but for this table (only) I only want half (but more on smaller displays). I thought I could do it with something like this, but nope.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
<table class="table">
....
</table>
</div></div>
```

Comment: You can do with the Bootstrap columns like this https://jsfiddle.net/84kve8oc/ or if you don't want to use bootstrap column class you can try `width: 50vw`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use

```
.table{
 width:50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
 .table{
  width:70%;
 }
}
```